# What went wrong: Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\user\project\Food\userApp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\macto.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\ea4ydi90mwjg9g63m7r6nimmx).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1